# conda update --all fails after fresh install (Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a fresh, initialized installation of Anaconda Python from the file **Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh**.  Immediately after installation, I run `conda update --all` and it fails during the "Solving Environment" phase, as shown:

```bash
$ conda update --all

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Found conflicts! failed - \ 

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment: 

Specifications: 
- conda-env -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*|3.5.*'] 
- navigator-updater -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*'] 

Your python: python=3.8
```

After that, it lists the `- defaults/*` for various packages and ultimately cannot go further.  Does anyone have insights on what might be going on here?

---

### Conda Info

```bash
$ conda info

    active environment : None 
      user config file : /home/user/.condarc 
populated config files : 
         conda version : 4.9.2 
   conda-build version : 3.20.5 
        python version : 3.8.5.final.0 
      virtual packages : __glibc=2.17=0 
                         __unix=0=0  
                         __archspec=1=x86_64 
      base environment : /usr/local/anaconda38 
          channel URLs : repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64 
                         repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch 
                         repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64 
                         repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch 
         package cache : /usr/local/anaconda38/pkgs /home/user/.conda/pkgs 
      envs directories : /home/user/.conda/envs 
                         /usr/local/anaconda38/envs 
              platform : linux-64 
            user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Linux/3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 centos/7.6.1810 glibc/2.17 
               UID:GID : 722097580:1044000513 
            netrc file : None
          offline mode : False
```

Comment: More output:

Found conflicts!  failed                                                                    -                                                                             \

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - conda-env -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*|3.5.*']
  - navigator-updater -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.8

Comment: active environment : None
       user config file : /home/user/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __glibc=2.17=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /usr/local/anaconda38
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch

Comment: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /usr/local/anaconda38/pkgs
                          /home/user/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/user/.conda/envs
                          /usr/local/anaconda38/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Linux/3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 centos/7.6.1810 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 722097580:1044000513
             netrc file : None

Comment: offline mode : False

Comment: Is this really a fresh install? Where is `conda-env` installed? That package is from way back when `conda` and `conda-env` used to be separate packages (at least a few years old). There is no way Anaconda installer includes it; it must be coming from another Python installation or `site-packages`. Ensure that other Python’s are not on PATH and PYTHONPATH is clear.

Comment: @merv Thank you for mentioning the conda-env.  There was a fragment of a former installation that was interfering with the new installation.  removing the last bits of the old installation resolved the problem.

Comment: Good to know that was it, and glad you finally got it resolved! I wrote up the suggestion in a general form as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible Old Conda Leaking into Environment

The presence of the `conda-env` package in the conflict report is indicative of this not being a completely fresh install. Specifically, that package was merged into the main `conda` Python package starting with Conda v4.2.0 (in 2016!) and so should no longer exist as a standalone package. This is possibly a relic from a previous Conda installation or something that may have been installed via `pip`, perhaps at a user lever (i.e., `pip install --user`).

This also means that some other Python installation or at least a `site-packages` is leaking into the environment, which can interfere with Conda's expected behavior. Normal Conda environment functionality assumes full isolation of environments.

### Suggested Resolution

Try to establish where the `conda-env` package is installed and remove it. One can get of list of where Python is sourcing packages from using

```bash
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
```

Anything coming from outside the Anaconda 3 installation would be a leak. Additionally, remove any other packages that might be installed at a user-level (typically at `~/.local/lib/python*.*/site-packages`), since Python will always attempt to load from there if a matching Python version is present. In your specific case, you want to check the v3.8 subdirectory, but generally one should avoid any user-level package installation (see [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)).

Another potential route of leakage is through `PYTHONPATH`. Ensure that this is not set.